# How to create react native editor and output

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I can create html editor using iframe tag in .html files. Same like that I want to make my own react native editor.
I think if I append the .js(component) file dynamically my problem will solve.

What I tried?
I tried to store it the whole .js file into a variable and tried to append it into a View.

Note : I am very new to react native.